# How to express $f(n\alpha)$ in terms of $f(\alpha)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

> **Original question:** Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function defined by $f(x)=\dfrac{a^x-a^{-x}}{2}$, where $a>0$ and $a\ne 1$, and $\alpha$ be a real number such that $f(\alpha)=1$. Find $f(2\alpha)$.$^1$

A few years ago, I was a high school student and solved it. Now I am reading the book again, because I has begun teaching my cousin since last week. When I revisited the question, suddenly I wanted to find $f(2\alpha)$, $f(3\alpha)$, $f(4\alpha),\;\dots$
\begin{align}
f(2\alpha)&=\frac{a^{2\alpha}-a^{-2\alpha}}{2}\\
&=\frac{(a^{\alpha}-a^{-\alpha})(a^{\alpha}+a^{-\alpha})}{2}\\
&=f(\alpha)\sqrt{a^{2\alpha}+2+a^{-2\alpha}}\\
&=f(\alpha)\sqrt{(a^{\alpha}-a^{-\alpha})^2+4}\\
&=f(\alpha)\sqrt{4(f(\alpha))^2+4}\\
f(3\alpha)&=f(\alpha)(4(f(\alpha))^2+3)\;(\text{calculations skipped})\\
f(4\alpha)&=f(\alpha)(4(f(\alpha))^2+2)\sqrt{4(f(\alpha))^2+4}
\end{align}

> **My question:** Can we express $f(n\alpha)$ in terms of $f(\alpha)$? (Here $f(\alpha)$ isn't necessarily $1$.)

**Attempt:** It is known that $x^n - y^n = (x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+x^{n-3}y^2+\cdots+y^{n-1})$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$, so
$$f(n\alpha)=\frac{a^{n\alpha}-a^{-n\alpha}}{2}=\frac{(a^{\alpha}-a^{-\alpha})(a^{(n-1)\alpha}+a^{(n-3)\alpha}+\cdots+a^{(3-n)\alpha}+a^{(1-n)\alpha})}{2}.$$
However, $(a^{(n-1)\alpha}+a^{(n-3)\alpha}+\cdots+a^{(3-n)\alpha}+a^{(1-n)\alpha})$ term is annoying me. I think it will be $2(f((n-1)\alpha)+f((n-3)\alpha)+\cdots+?)$, but I have no idea how to do next.

Partial solution is also appreciated.

---

$^1$ It was translated from Korean to English by me. Reference: Sunwook Hwang and 12 other authors (2010).『수학Ⅰ 익힘책』. Seoul: (주)좋은책신사고. page 62.

Comment: You should find $\alpha$ first from $f(\alpha)=1$

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp I'm sorry, but I think it's not a good idea. I can find $\alpha=\log_a (1+\sqrt{2})$, but does it help me?

Comment: can you not simplify you're formulae by subbing in $f(\alpha)=1$ or do you want it left general?

Comment: And... in my question, $f(\alpha)$ doesn't need to be $1$.

Comment: I think hyperbolic function may help.

Comment: So, why do you confuse us with this? Just delete it from the question.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Sorry, confusing you was not my purpose, but the original problem was asking me to find the value of $f(2\alpha)$ given that of $f(\alpha)$. Also, I thought that I have to cite the problem precisely. Is deleting $f(\alpha)=1$ required absolutely? Instead, Could I emphasize my own question, leaving it?

Comment: I just run a quick calculation would $$\dfrac{(\sqrt{1+f(x)^2}+f(x))^n+(\sqrt{1+f(x)^2}-f(x))^n}{2}$$, i need bit checking though.

Comment: Ah, I found the answer. Thanks to Friedrich Philipp. It was in fact a good idea. But in this situation, What I have to do? Updating my question post, or posting answer myself?

Comment: You could add it to your answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can rewrite the function as

$$f(x)=\sinh(x\ln a)$$

then $f(nx)=\sinh(nx\ln a)$

let, $x\ln a=t$ then, $f(t)=\sinh(t)$ and $f(nt)=\sinh(nt)$
also, $\cosh(t)=\sqrt{1+f(t)^2}$

Finally use the fact that $$\sinh(nt)=\dfrac{(\cosh(t)+\sinh(t))^n-(\cosh(t)-\sinh(t))^n}{2}$$

Answer (score 3):

From $f(\alpha)=\frac{a^\alpha - a^{-\alpha}}{2}$, we can induce the quadratic equation for $a^{\alpha}$:
$$
a^{2\alpha}-2f(\alpha)a^{\alpha}-1=0.
$$
By the quadratic formula, we get
$$
a^{\alpha}=f(\alpha)\pm \sqrt{(f(\alpha))^2+1}
$$
and using $a^{\alpha}>0$ we eliminate one possibility. Thus
$$
a^{n\alpha}=(a^{\alpha})^n =\left(\sqrt{f(\alpha)^2+1} + f(\alpha)\right)^n
$$
and
\begin{align}
a^{-n\alpha}&=\frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{f(\alpha)^2+1} + f(\alpha)\right)^n}\\
&=\frac{\left(\sqrt{f(\alpha)^2+1} - f(\alpha)\right)^n}{\left(\sqrt{f(\alpha)^2+1} + f(\alpha)\right)^n\left(\sqrt{f(\alpha)^2+1} - f(\alpha)\right)^n}\\
&=\frac{\left(\sqrt{f(\alpha)^2+1} - f(\alpha)\right)^n}{(f(\alpha)^2+1-f(\alpha)^2)^n}\\
&=\left(\sqrt{f(\alpha)^2+1} - f(\alpha)\right)^n.
\end{align}
Therefore
$$
f(n\alpha)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\left(\sqrt{f(\alpha)^2+1} + f(\alpha)\right)^n -\left(\sqrt{f(\alpha)^2+1} - f(\alpha)\right)^n\right)
$$
Checking the formula for $n=2$:
\begin{align}
f(2\alpha)&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\left(\sqrt{f(\alpha)^2+1} + f(\alpha)\right)^2 -\left(\sqrt{f(\alpha)^2+1} - f(\alpha)\right)^2\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}(f(\alpha)^2+1+2f(\alpha)\sqrt{f(\alpha)^2+1} + f(\alpha)^2 -f(\alpha)^2-1+2f(\alpha)\sqrt{f(\alpha)^2+1}-f(\alpha)^2)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 4f(\alpha)\sqrt{f(\alpha)^2+1}\\
&=2f(\alpha)\sqrt{f(\alpha)^2+1}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Let $a^x = y$, then $y$ can be solved in terms of the RHS. Let $f(\alpha) = A$, from:

$$
y - \frac{1}{y} = 2A
$$
with the quadratic root formula, we have
$$y = g(A) = A + \sqrt{1 + A^2}$$
After this it is a matter of substitution and simplification:
$$
f(n \alpha) = \frac{1}{2} (g(A)^n - g(A)^{-n})
$$

Comment: Should $y$ be $A+\sqrt{A^2+1}$?

Comment: @choco_addicted You are right, I have fixed the error, thanks!